# using adb in command prompt, but receiving error

Tags: adb

```
C:\Users\purpl\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>ADB SHELL RM /DATA/SYSTEM/PASSWORD.KEY

adb: usage: unknown command SHELL
```

This line should run android sdk, but it doesn't and comes up with this

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Windows file system `adb` commands are case-sensitive even on Windows.